# View Localization with Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, localization, razor-pages

We can localize Razor Pages by injecting the `IViewLocalizer`. This is very helpful, but for Razor Pages with a lot of content I would like to create location dependent Razor Pages like `Index.de.cshtml` or `Index.en.cshtml`. This is possible for views as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request) with `builder.Services.AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)`. Is there a similar way for Razor Pages?

Comment: You can try https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/master/samples/Mvc.LocalizedRazorPages. Check it with .net core 6 with razor pages. Works.